# Smack doesn't recognize type="result" stanza when IQProvider is enabled

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

**tl;dr**

When registering an IQProvider, I don't get an answer in the `StanzaListener`, I might not have understood precisely how IQProviders work, but don't know where to start.

---

I'm using Smack to send and receive some custom IQ's. Here's the code I'm using to send the custom IQ.

```
iq.setFrom(JidCreate.fullFrom(CLIENT_USER));
iq.setTo(JidCreate.fullFrom(SERVER_USER));
xmppConnection.sendIqWithResponseCallback(iq, new StanzaListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
        handleReply((WedooIQ) packet);
    }
}, new ExceptionCallback()
    @Override
    public void processException(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

All right. I'm certain that the correct answer is sent, because debug mode is showing me what I want to see. The result stanzas are provided by a node client on the other side, so that's not of concern for this question.

---

**Here's what's not working out for me:** I'm getting an answer in the `StanzaListener()`, but of course, I can't do much with it if I don't want to do all the parsing on my own. I'm told to implement a IQProvider and register it - so I do:

```
ProviderManager.addIQProvider(Xxx.ELEMENT_NAME, Yyy.NAMESPACE, new ZzzIQProvider());
```

But when this is registered, I don't get an answer anymore and instead, there's a timeout exception after those 5 seconds

```
System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Waited for response using: IQReplyFilter ......
```

I was figuring the `IQProvider` would make it so that I get a more usable object in the `StanzaListener` from above. How does this work? I have read the documentation on this on the [smack homepage](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.6/documentation/providers.html), but I don't understand how to receive IQs, I only understand how to register a provider without any visible effect to me.

---

Probably just missing something small here, any help is highly appreciated since I've been sitting on this for several days now.

Comment: Do you send multiple IQ/stanza at the same time??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer my question, one sec

Comment: I am facing same problem, and I found a bug on my IQProvider.
IQProvider returns IQ with different stanza id, so StanzaListener wouldn't capture the result IQ with StanzaFilter.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my parser where I didn't read all tags to the end. So it would silently fail without any notice. Make sure you're reading the whole XML correctly while not misusing the parser or parser until class

If that's not it, here's another idea from @calvinfly in the comments:

> I am facing same problem, and I found a bug on my IQProvider.
>   IQProvider returns IQ with different stanza id, so StanzaListener wouldn't capture the result IQ with StanzaFilter.....